# Why is my C# application code not working with my GUI?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Ok so I am adding on to my last project, where I created a shark race. Everything ran smoothly, and then it got fancy.

Here are the requirements:
1) Declare all of the instance variables to be public properties defined with get and set
accessor methods along with corresponding private backing fields.
2) Remove the MyBet instance variable from the Guy class and instead provide an
array within the Form1 class that holds each Bet instance. The betting parlor should
now allow for each Guy to place multiple bets. However, the Amount of each Bet
should be deducted from the Cash property of each Guy at the time the Bet is made.
Winnings are thus only positive quantities that are paid out after the race.
3) Have a scoreboard (or some type of visual display) that indicates the order in which
each racer finished, allowing for the possibility that there are ties for 1st, 2nd, or 3rd
places.

I'm getting about 50 of the same error, and it seems like they are all very quick fixes, but for some reason I can't figure them out. Thanks in advance!

With that in mind, here are my forms:

Forms Class:

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace project1
{
    public partial class Game : Form
    {
        private Shark[] sharks;
        private Guy[] guys;
        private Guy selectedGuy;
        private Bet[] bets;
        private int[] winners = new int[4];

```
    public Game()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Random moreRandom = new Random();

        int start = myTrack.Location.X;
        int finish = myTrack.Width - 65;

        sharks = new Shark[4]
            {
                new Shark() {myRandom = moreRandom, myPictureBox = myShark1, myPBStart = start, trackLength = finish},
                new Shark() {myRandom = moreRandom, myPictureBox = myShark2, myPBStart = start, trackLength = finish},
                new Shark() {myRandom = moreRandom, myPictureBox = myShark3, myPBStart = start, trackLength = finish},
                new Shark() {myRandom = moreRandom, myPictureBox = myShark4, myPBStart = start, trackLength = finish}
            };

        guys = new Guy[3]
            {
                new Guy() {Name="Joe", Moneys=50, MyRB=rbGuy1, GuyLabel=labelBet1},
                new Guy() {Name="Bob", Moneys=75, MyRB=rbGuy2, GuyLabel=labelBet2},
                new Guy() {Name="Al", Moneys=45, MyRB=rbGuy3, GuyLabel=labelBet3}
            };

        bets = new Bet[12];

        for (int = 0; i<bets.Length; i++)
        {
            bets[i] = Bet.EmptyBet;
        }

        selectedGuy = guys[0];
        rbGuy1.Tag = guys[0];
        rbGuy2.Tag = guys[1];
        rbGuy3.Tag = guys[2];            

        updateGui();
    }

    private void myChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selectedGuy = getSelectedGuy(sender);
        betterLabel.Text = selectedGuy.Name;
    }

    private void betAmountValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateMin();
    }

    private void bet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int bet = (int) betAmount.Value;
        int myFish = (int) sharkNumber.Value;
        Bet temp = selectedGuy.placeBet(bet,myFish);
        if (!temp == Bet.EmptyBet)
        {
        for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            if (guys[i].Name == selectedGuy.Name)
            {
                bets[i + (3 * myFish)] = temp;
            }
        }

            /*for (int = 0; i<bets.Length, i++)
            {
            bets[i] = temp;
            }*/

        }
        //selectedGuy.placeBet(bet, myFish);
        updateGui();
    }

    private void raceBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        betBtn.Enabled = false;
        Application.DoEvents();
        //bool noWinner = true;

        Random rand = new Random();
        /*int winner = rand.Next(1,5);

        showWinner(winner-1);
        collectBets(winner-1);
        */
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
            winners[i] = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            bool placed = false;
            int temp;
            while (!placed)
            {
                temp = rand.Next(0,4);
                if (winners[temp] == 0)
                {
                    winners[temp] = i;
                    placed = true;
                }
            }
        }

        showWinner(winners[0] - 1);
        collectBets(winners[0] - 1);

        /*while(noWinner)
        {
            for (int fish = 0; fish < sharks.Length; fish++)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                if(sharks[fish].Swim())
                {
                    showWinner(fish);
                    collectBets(fish);
                    noWinner = false;
                }
            }
        }*/

        updateGui();

        betBtn.Enabled = true;
    }



    private void showWinner(int fish)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Winner Winner People Dinner! \nShark {0} won!", fish + 1));

    }

    private void collectBets(int fish)
    {
        for (int guyNumber = 0; guyNumber < guys.Length; guyNumber++)
        {
            guys[guyNumber].collect(betTotal(), winningSharkTotal());
            guys[guyNumber].resetBet();

        }
    }

    private void updateMin()
    {
        minBetLabel.Text = string.Format("Minimum bet: 5 bucks", betAmount.Value);
    }

    private Guy getSelectedGuy(object sender)
    {
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
        return (Guy)rb.Tag;
    }

    private void updateGui()
    {
        for (int guyNumber = 0; guyNumber < guys.Length; guyNumber++)
        {
            guys[guyNumber].updateLabels();
        }

        for (int fish = 0; fish < sharks.Length; fish++)
        {
            sharks[fish].startPosition();
        }

        /*betTable1 = bets[0];
        betTable2 = bets[1];
        betTable3 = bets[2];*/


        bet1_1.Text = string.Format(bets[0].Amount);
        bet1_2.Text = bets[1].Amount;
        bet1_3.Text = bets[2].Amount;
        bet2_1.Text = bets[3].Amount;
        bet2_2.Text = bets[4].Amount;
        bet2_3.Text = bets[5].Amount;
        bet3_1.Text = bets[6].Amount;
        bet3_2.Text = bets[7].Amount;
        bet3_3.Text = bets[8].Amount;
        bet4_1.Text = bets[9].Amount;
        bet4_2.Text = bets[10].Amount;
        bet4_3.Text = bets[11].Amount;

        updateMin();

        firstWinner.Text = winners[0];
        secondWinner.Text = winners[1];
        thirdWinner.Text = winners[2];
        fourthWinner.Text = winners[3];

    }

    private int betTotal()
    {
    int Result = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<bets.Length; i++)
    {
    Result += bets[i].Amount;
    }
    return Result;
    }

    private int winningSharkTotal(int Winner)
    {
    int Result = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        Result += bets[i+(winner*3)];

    }
    return Result;


    }

}
```

}

Sharks Class:

```
using System;
```

using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace project1
{
    public class Shark
    {
        public int myPBStart; // Where the PictureBox starts
        public int trackLength; // How long the racetrack is
        public PictureBox myPictureBox = null; // The PictureBox object
        public int location = 0; // My location on the racetrack
        public Random myRandom; // An instance of Random

```
    public Shark()
    {
        location = 0;
        myPictureBox = new PictureBox();
        myRandom = new Random();
        trackLength = 100;
        myPBStart = 0;
    }

    public bool Swim()
    {
        int distance = myRandom.Next(1, 4);
        location += distance;

        movePB(distance);

        return location > trackLength;
    }

    private void movePB(int distance)
    {
        Point p = myPictureBox.Location;
        p.X += distance;
        myPictureBox.Location = p;
    }

    public void startPosition()
    {
        location = myPBStart;

        Point p = myPictureBox.Location;
        p.X = location;
        myPictureBox.Location = p;
    }
}
```

}

Guy Class:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

namespace project1
{
    public class Guy
    {
        private string myName;
        //public Bet myBet;
        private int cash;

```
    // The last two fields are the the guy's GUI controls on the form
    private RadioButton myRadioButton;
    private Label myLabel;
    const int minBet = 5;
    const int maxBet = 15;

    public Guy()
    {
        //myBet = emptyBet();

        //myBet = new Bet() { amount = 0, fish = 0, better = this };

    }

    public void updateLabels()
    {
        get{
        // Set my label to my bet's description and its label
        myLabel.Text = myBet.Description();

        // cash radio buttons
        myRadioButton.Text = radioButtonText();
        }
    }

    public void resetBet()
    {
        // reset my bet to 0
        myBet = Bet.EmptyBet;
    }

    public string Name{
    get{
    return myName;
    }

    }

    public int Moneys
    {
        get
        {
            return cash;
        }
    }

    public RadioButton MyRB
    {
        get
        {
            return myRadioButton;
        }
    }

    public Label GuyLabel
    {
        get
        {
            return myLabel;
        }
    }

    public Bet placeBet(int amount, int fish)
    {
        if (amount > cash || amount < minBet || amount > maxBet)
        {
            return Bet.EmptyBet;
            //return false;
        }

        cash -= amount;
        return new Bet() {Amount=amount, Fish=fish, better=this};

        //return true;
    }

    public void collect(int pool, int sharkPool)
    {
        get{
        return cash += myBet.payout(pool, sharkPool);
        }
    }


    private string radioButtonText()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} has {1} bucks", myName, cash);
    }
}
```

}

Bet Class:

```
namespace project1
```

{
    public class Bet
    {
        private int amount; // The amount of cash that was bet
        private int fish; // The number of the shark the bet is on.
        public Guy better; // The guy who placed the bet

```
    public static Bet EmptyBet{
    get
        {
            return new Bet() { amount = 0, fish = 0, better = this };
        }

    }

    public string Description
    {
    get
        {
            if (noBet())
            {
            return string.Format("{0} hasn't placed a bet", better.Name);    
            }
            else
            {
            return string.Format("{0} bets {1} bucks on shark #{2}", better.Name, amount, fish);    
            }
        }
    }

    public int payout(int pool, int sharkPool)
    {
        get{

        return ((pool * (0.85))/sharkPool) * amount;

        /*if (myShark(pool))
        {
            return amount;
        }
        else
        {
            return -amount;
        }*/
        }
    }

    /*private bool myShark(int winner)
    {
        return winner == fish;
    }*/

    private bool noBet()
    {
        return amount == 0;
    }

    public int Amount 
    {
       get
        {
        return amount;
        }
    }

    public int Fish
    {
        get
        {
            return fish;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Far too much code to reasonably expect anyone to review. Maybe set up an appointment with your TA.

Comment: Yep. +1 vote to close for making me scroll too much.

Comment: why don't you paste the whole solution?

Comment: and paste your database too, so we can look at all the users.

Comment: Among many other things, your Guy class has a label and a radio button. Objects map back to real world entities, and last I checked, guys don't have radio buttons.

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing the concept of a method and a property. First remove the `get { }` from you methods and then consider whether `void` is the right return type. From the looks of it you are returning some sort of `decimal` value.

```
public void collect(int pool, int sharkPool)
{
    get{
    return cash += myBet.payout(pool, sharkPool);
    }
}
```

In the following code, by including the literal `0.85` the resulting value will have type `double`. The return type  of the method is `int`.

```
public int payout(int pool, int sharkPool)
{
    get{

    return ((pool * (0.85))/sharkPool) * amount;

    /*if (myShark(pool))
    {
        return amount;
    }
    else
    {
        return -amount;
    }*/
    }
}
```

As I mentioned previously, remove the `get` and mark the return type as `double`.

```
public double payout(int pool, int sharkPool)
{
    return ((pool * (0.85))/sharkPool) * amount;
}
```

There is more but I think you have bigger fish to fry. I would go back and review the fundamentals of the C# syntax and try to get a better understanding of numeric data types.
When working with currency you really need to use `decimal`.

Comment: +1 for taking the extra effort!

Comment: I've seen this kind of method 2 in Guys class and 1 in Bet class.

Answer (score 2):

Chaos is correct (and props for seeing what I overlooked). It also looks like there are some type conversion errors being generated from assigning Bet.Amount to a TextBox.  Call ToString() on your integer values, and these errors should go away.

> Error 42 Cannot implicitly convert
>   type 'int' to 'string'

And **please** remember that UI elements (like labels, radio buttons, picture boxes) do not belong on business objects like Guys or Sharks. This is design decision that is far more fundamental than fixing a few compiler errors (though I'm sure it doesn't seem that way at the moment).

Comment: thank you so much! However, winners[0]-[4] aren't strings are they? So would I do something like.. firstWinner.Text = ConvertToString(winners[0]); ?

Comment: firstWinner.Text = winners[0].ToString();

Comment: That's probably the simplest way of doing it, obviously it doesn't check for null values, perform formatting, or perform localization.